# Convert set of images to video using ffmpeg with frame step

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert images00001.jpg up to images00400.jpg with frame step of 20 to video. So far I have this but it includes all frames from 1 to 400:

```
   !ffmpeg -start_number 1 -i images%05d.jpg -vframes 400 -vcodec mpeg4 result.mp4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -start_number 1 -framerate 25 -i images%05d.jpg -vf framestep=20,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB -c:v mpeg4 result.mp4
```

This will make for a 0.8 second video.

Comment: Thank you! I have one more, how do I force it to replace the file if the file is already existing? So I wont need to type in 'Y'

Comment: it is only displaying 2 images why not complete folder i have multiple images when i increase start number it display next of 2 images. can you please help me what should i do?